# Tengo un error de formato JSON en Angular al hacer una petición

Tags: nodejs, angular, http

Tengo el siguiente header "x-token" en postman:

[image: imagen header]
Entonces, en mi servicio en Angular envío el token almacenado en el localStorage al header:

```
 validarToken(){
    let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('x-token', localStorage.getItem('token') || '');
    return this.authService.get("/api/auth/relogin",{headers})
}
```

Hago el subscribe al servicio en otro componente:

```
login(){

    this.authService.validarToken().subscribe(token => console.log(token));

}
```

Pero me sale el siguiente error en la consola:

[image: error en la consola]

He probado "soluciones" como agregar el responseType:'text' a la petición pero no lo que me devuelve en la consola es esto:

[image: imagen responseType]

Comment: Si añades `responseType: 'text'` al servicio lo que haces es que angular no parsee la respuesta a JSON. Lo cual en este caso sería correcto porque tu API está devolviéndote una página HTML y no JSON. Estás seguro de que ese servicio de angular está llamando a la misma API que tu postman?? Porque si en angular llamas a `/api/auth/relogin` estás llamando a una ruta de angular... no sé qué esperas conseguir, según el error has llamado a localhost:4200 (ANGULAR) y en tu postman a localhost:4000, tu API. Como decía... te falta poner la IP a la que debe llamar el servicio.

Comment: De acuerdo con el comentario de arriba, parece que te falta el url? De hecho, viendo mejor, la respuesta que te da en Angular es de `localhost:4200` y no de `localhost:4000` como lo muestras en Postman.

Comment: lo que tratas de parsear no es un json.